# Is a possible way with .htaccess to fix HPKP?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Deciding to set up the HTTP Public Key Pinning Process i have tried some codes with my .htaccess it looks like that :

```html
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
Header always set X-FRAME-OPTIONS "SAMEORIGIN"
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" env=HTTPS
Header set Public-Key-Pins "pin-sha256=\"klO23nT2ehFDXCfx3eHTDRESMz3asj1muO+4aIdjiuY=\"; pin-sha256=\"633lt352PKRXbOwf4xSEa1M517scpD3l5f79xMD9r9Q=\"; max-age=2592000; includeSubDomains"
```

Is it possible to succeed in with the .htaccess or i'm going in a bad way ? Should i go deeper and set HPKP in APACHE rules ?

Some advices will be appreciate !

Anyway have a good day :)

Comment: Support for HPKP is going to be dropped by browsers. (Maybe it already has been?) I wouldn’t bother.

Comment: Do you mean browsers are gonna stop this security process ?

Comment: @Ryan because actually i'm using latest firefox and when i look into the network console in security part when i load a page i've got disabled HPKP but thanks for the advice dude